# How to write in a SqlDescriptor with a jdbc prepared statement into a tsrange column?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I followed the excellent guide [How to map Java and SQL arrays with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) to map the special sql type `tsrange` to hibernate. I decided to use Java and SQL descriptors and not a user type, because the jdbc sql handling should be better.

When I try to persist an entity with a column named time range and the type tsrange, I got always: `ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) ERROR: column "time_range" is of type tsrange but expression is of type character varying
  Hinweis: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

My understanding is, that I need to write a special/non standard sql type with the setObject method and the type Type.OTHER or Type.JAVA_OBJECT. What is the prefered way, to put a range sql type into a PreparedStatement?

The BasicBinder source, where I fill the jdbc prepared statement, sqlString contains `"[2019-01-14 13:06:26, 2019-01-14 13:12:39]"`:

```
@Override
public <X> ValueBinder<X> getBinder(JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor) {
    return new BasicBinder<X>(javaTypeDescriptor, this) {

        @Override
        protected void doBind(PreparedStatement st, X value, int index, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
            String sqlString = javaTypeDescriptor.toString(value);
            // I tried the following statements:
            //st.setObject(index, sqlString, getSqlType());
            //st.setObject(index, sqlString);
            //st.setString(index, sqlString+"::tsrange");
            st.setString(index, sqlString);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doBind(CallableStatement st, X value, String name, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
            st.setObject(name, javaTypeDescriptor.toString(value));
        }
    };
}
```

Here are the column definition of the entity:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Basic
@Column(nullable = false, name = "time_range", columnDefinition = "tsrange")
@Type(type="com.example.model.types.TsRange")
private PgTsRange timeRange;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The `tsrange` can be written as string of the form `"[2019-01-14 13:06:26, 2019-01-14 13:12:39]"` into the `PreparedStatement st` with `st.setObject(index, sqlString, Type.OTHER);`

Here is the working `TsRangeSqlTypeDescriptor` class:

```
package com.example.galea.model.types;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.ValueBinder;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.ValueExtractor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.WrapperOptions;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.SqlTypeDescriptor;

public class TsRangeSqlTypeDescriptor implements SqlTypeDescriptor {

    /**  */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4377165492827156136L;

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TsRangeSqlTypeDescriptor.class);

    public static final TsRangeSqlTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = new TsRangeSqlTypeDescriptor();

    @Override
    public int getSqlType() {
        return Types.OTHER; // <--- This is importand!
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canBeRemapped() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public <X> ValueBinder<X> getBinder(JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor) {
        return new BasicBinder<X>(javaTypeDescriptor, this) {

            @Override
            protected void doBind(PreparedStatement st, X value, int index, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
                String sqlString = javaTypeDescriptor.toString(value);

                // Here is the solution with Type.OTHER
                st.setObject(index, sqlString, getSqlType());
            }

            @Override
            protected void doBind(CallableStatement st, X value, String name, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
                st.setObject(name, javaTypeDescriptor.toString(value));
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public <X> ValueExtractor<X> getExtractor(JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor) {
        return new BasicExtractor<X>(javaTypeDescriptor, this) {

            @Override
            protected X doExtract(ResultSet rs, String name, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
                if(javaTypeDescriptor instanceof TsRangeJavaTypeDescriptor) {
                    TsRangeJavaTypeDescriptor rangeJavaTypeDescriptor = (TsRangeJavaTypeDescriptor) javaTypeDescriptor;

                    Object pgObject = rs.getObject(name);
                    Object valueRaw;
                    // Ugly, but I can not cast PGobject
                    try {
                        valueRaw = pgObject.getClass().getMethod(getValue, null).invoke(pgObject);
                        if(valueRaw instanceof String) {
                            String value = (String) valueRaw;
                            return (X) rangeJavaTypeDescriptor.wrap(value, options);
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                        log.error(Failed to parse pgObject,e);
                    }
                }
                return javaTypeDescriptor.wrap(rs.getObject(name), options);
            }

            @Override
            protected X doExtract(CallableStatement statement, int index, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
                return javaTypeDescriptor.wrap(statement.getObject(index), options);
            }

            @Override
            protected X doExtract(CallableStatement statement, String name, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
                return javaTypeDescriptor.wrap(statement.getObject(name), options);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

One ugly part is the first `doExtract` method. This is not in the scope of my question, but it was impossible for me to cast `rs.getObject(name)` to PGobject. I putted also `org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.5` to my dependencies but I got strange classloading warnings and casting was impossible. But the dirty hack with reflection works. I use wildfy 14.

Answer (score 1):

> The Hibernate Types project offers a [`PostgreSQLRangeType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-range-column-type-jpa-hibernate/) supports the PostgreSQL `TSRANGE` column type.

The first thing you need to do is to use the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Afterward, you can map your PostgreSQL ranges like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
@TypeDef(
    typeClass = PostgreSQLRangeType.class,
    defaultForType = Range.class
)
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;
 
    private String title;
 
    @Column(
        name = "price_cent_range",
        columnDefinition = "numrange"
    )
    private Range<BigDecimal> priceRange;
 
    @Column(
        name = "discount_date_range",
        columnDefinition = "daterange"
    )
    private Range<LocalDate> discountDateRange;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `Range` and `PostgreSQLRangeType` classes are from the Hibernate Types project.